# content based swapping of two columns

Tags: r, awk, sed, dataframe

I have swapped the columns in a file using the below code

```
awk '{ t=$1 ; $1=$2; $2=t; print }' inp_file > out_file
```

I would like to swap the files based on the content in the second column (Content based swapping).

Input file:

```
226 PRE1 0 0 2 2
228 PRE2 0 0 2 -9
CCC1 1 0 0 2 2
CCC2 1 0 0 2 2
```

Output file:

```
PRE1 226 0 0 2 2
PRE2 228 0 0 2 -9
CCC1 1 0 0 2 2
CCC2 1 0 0 2 2
```

Columns has to be swapped only when the second column has the content `PRE`.

Would you suggest the ways to achieve it ?

Comment: Are you looking for `awk`, `sed` or `r` solution?

Comment: @DavidArenburg anyone is fine. Would be happy to know & learn all, if possible :)

Comment: In R, if your data set called `df` and the column aren't factors, you could do something like `indx <- grepl("PRE", df[, 2]) ; df[indx, 1:2] <- df[indx, 2:1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is easy, add a condition before the action,

```
$ awk '$2 ~ /PRE/{ t=$1 ; $1=$2; $2=t}1' input
PRE1 226 0 0 2 2
PRE2 228 0 0 2 -9
CCC1 1 0 0 2 2
CCC2 1 0 0 2 2
```

**What it does?**

- `$2 ~ /PRE/` Regular expression match of column two with `PRE`
- We remove the `print` from action `{}` as we need to print always and not just when the pattern is matched.
- `1` The `1` at the end always evaluates to true, in which case the `awk` takes the default action to print the entire record.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution.

Answer (score 1):

sed version (keeping separator *as is*:

```
sed 's/^\([^[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\([[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\(PRE[^[:blank:]]*\)/\3\2\1/' inp_file > out_file
```

awk (first separator may be rewrite)

```
awk '{if((t=$2)~/PRE/){$2=$1;$1=t};print}' inp_file > out_file
```